# Android emulator Cannot Launch AVD in Emulator in OSX

Tags: android

Just started getting this.  No idea why.

[image]

I tried 3 different new devices and get this for all of them.

Comment: does it happen only with api23 ? What's the content of `system-images/android-23/` in your SDK directory ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use Genymotion as your emulator. Fast and easy to use. You just need virtual box to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the SDK manager and check if the components have been downloaded properly or not.

You might need to remove and re-download them as this happens if the image was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I just started getting something similar too.[image]

If I set the scale option to 'Auto' everything works as intended.  I assume Google have mode some changes but not updated everything properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the Android SDK worked.  Took a few attempts to get it right. Had to uninstall and then reinstall. Picked x86_64 image in the end

[image]

Then I was able to go to my various virtual devices and use the Repair Device links as seen here to fix them:

[image]